# How to round off the value and disabled the textbox after entering the value in textbox in ASP.net using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I want to round off the  value which is in  textbox, once value  enter in textbox and before cursor  moving to next field and also at the same time have to disable the textbox once round off get finished

Eg  if i enter 456.667 in textbox means before the cursor move to next field it round off the value 456.667 to 457. Here i tried On value change event function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function tSpeedValue()
    {
        debugger;
        var result = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>")
        var result1 = result.tofixed(0);
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="tSpeedValue"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onchange="tSpeedValue1"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here what is my doubt is here i get the value and also rounded off the value. now my doubt is how to assign the round off value again to  same textbox and also disable the textbox once round off. i have less knowledge in asp.net so only i ask this simple question as doubt. i tried my level best to explain the issue.Please any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I don't see how this is logically possible.  If you round the value and then disable the text box on value change, you will not be able to type in anything beyond a single digit number.  You'd be better off using an [input mask](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking).

Comment: @PaulAbbott disable is second thing first i want to know how to assign the round off value again to same textbox